# Metodo $_GET mas seguro Evitar que el usuario introduzca dato en la url

Tags: php

como se puede hacer mas seguro este metodo en php

```
if ($_GET['id']){
    $id = $_GET['id'];

}
```

Saludo.

Comment: Dependiendo de tu aplicación, si no quieres que el usuario ingrese datos por la url, lo mejor que puedes hacer es enviar esos datos a través de POST.

Comment: "mas seguro " en qué sentido?

Comment: Mas bien, añadir seguridad

Comment: Yo creo que está un poco amplia la pregunta @JosbertHernandez, hay muchas técnicas y formas de "mejorar la seguridad" con el manejo de datos, que pueden ir desde reemplazar unas pocas líneas hasta reescritura de la aplicación (casi) completa. Si lo que quieres es que no aparezca el dato en la URL, entonces puedes usar otro verbo HTTP (POST, PUT, DELETE) como lo dice Juan Pinzón más arriba, pero aún así depende lo que pretendas hacer.

Comment: @JosbertHernandez [*Los diez riesgos más críticos en Aplicaciones Web* (PDF)](https://www.owasp.org/images/5/5f/OWASP_Top_10_-_2013_Final_-_Espa%C3%B1ol.pdf) puede ser un muy excelente punto de partida. Cualquier cosa que diga [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org "https://www.owasp.org"), está bien. ;)

Comment: @JosbertHernandez usar POST/PUT/DELETE en vez de GET no hace más segura la aplicación desde el punto de vista de evitar que el usuario mande lo que quiera. Podría usar herramientas como [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) o [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) (más herramientas en esta [pregunta de SecEx](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/223/how-can-i-intercept-and-modify-http-requests).
Si provee ciertos beneficios como los enumerados en las respuestas de [acá](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198462/is-either-get-or-post-more-secure-than-the-other).

Comment: Gracias eso era lo que necesitaba

Comment: @JosbertHernandez, qué es lo que necesitabas? Podrías clarificar tu pregunta?

Comment: @ElAsiduo Simplemente añadir seguridad a ese codigo

Answer (score 2):

Empecemos por filtrar la entrada del usuario.

Supongamos que los IDs válidos solo pueden ser números enteros. Puedes usar la función filter_var para aceptar solo este tipo de dato, y evitar que se introduzcan textos y hasta comandos de SQL.

Basándome en tu ejemplo mínimo, yo agregaría algo así:

```
if ($_GET['id']){
    $id = filter_var($_GET['id'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT));
    if( !$id ) { die('Intento de contaminar consulta'); }
    // código para procesar Id numérico
}
```

Esto se basa en que la función [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/es/function.filter-var.php) devuelve `FALSE` si no pasó el filtro, con lo que puedes abortar la consulta, devolviendo o no un mensaje al usuario, o procesarla sin ese dato en concreto.

Pero esto sería solo un primer paso, como te han comentado otros, tu pregunta es muy amplia, puedes añadir muchísimos niveles de seguridad. Las preguntas que debes de hacerte son más concretas cómo ¿qué quieres proteger? ¿qué arriesgas si no lo haces? ¿cuánto te cuesta hacerlo? ¿se justifica el valor del activo a proteger por lo que cuesta hacerlo? Y ya de ahí puedes partir en medidas concretas, pero sí, la validación y filtrado de entradas del usuario son básicas.

Comment: Esto si que me ayudo, Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Expandiendo la respuesta de Jesús Franco:

Si el **id** es númerico, debería ser suficiente:

```
$id = filter_var($_GET['id'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT));
```

Dependiendo de la situación puedes también utlizar el cast a int.

```
$id = (int)$_GET['id'] // devuelve 0 si id no es númerico o equivalente a 
0 , más rápido que intval()
```

Eso sería últil si asumimos uqe el **id** es:

- siempre un integer
- siempre mayor que zero (si zero devuleves 404)
- buscas mejorar el rendimiento

Un ejemplo es lá página de usuario: https://stackoverflow.com/users/275882

La diferencía fundamental entre **cast a (int)** y **filter_var** es el cast siempre devuelve un int, y filter_var solo te dice si es un int.

Si el **id** es texto:

```
$id= filter_var($_GET['id'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Más info: http://php.net/manual/es/function.filter-var.php

Si usas un editor de texto en tu aplicación web (textarea) es recomendable pasar el input HTML Purifier.

http://htmlpurifier.org/

Comment: Qué bueno que incluyes otros filtros de `filter_var`, pero no es equivalente el uso de intval, porque `$id` podría ser cero y aún así ser válido, la ventaja de filter_var es que devuelve explícitamente `FALSE` si no pasó el filtrado. Gracias por la recomendación de **htmlpurifier**, no lo conocía.

Comment: Por eso pusé "Dependiendo de la situación". Quizas debería editarlo y explicarlo mejor :-)

Comment: Sí exacto, al menos un ejemplo de situaciones en las que una opción es mejor que otra, a eso me refería, pero la respuesta me pareció buena de ahí mi voto a favor.

Answer (score 0):

Depende, puedes hacer lo que comenta Juan, enviar esos datos a través de POST o seguir las recomendaciones en caso de que sea por peligro de inyección SQL.

[Evitar inyección SQL:](http://php.net/manual/es/security.database.sql-injection.php)

- Nunca se conecte como superusuario o como propietario de la base de datos. Siempre utilice usuarios personalizados con privilegios muy limitados.
- Emplee sentencias preparadas con variables vinculadas. Son proporcionadas por PDO, MySQLi y otras bibliotecas.
- Compruebe si la entrada proporcionada tiene el tipo de datos previsto. PHP tiene un amplio rango de funciones para validar la entrada de datos, desde las más simples, encontradas en Funciones de variables y en Funciones del tipo carácter (p.ej., is_numeric(), ctype_digit() respectivamente), hasta el soporte para Expresiones regulares compatibles con Perl.
- Si la expresión espera una entrada numérica, considere verificar los datos con la función ctype_digit(), o silenciosamente cambie su tipo utilizando settype(), o emplee su representación numérica por medio de sprintf().
  [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) [php](/questions/tagged/php)[mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Una validación básica, si es un entero, es utilizar la función is_int

```
$id = null;
if(isset($_GET['id']) && is_int($_GET['id'])){
   $id = $_GET['id'];
}
```